# How to setup Defense+ in COMODO Internet Security 5.4?

Tags: comodo-firewall

I've tried to understand this reading the COMODO manual but I gave up :(

My problem: I have a Python script named test.py. Each time I modify it and run from the command prompt, COMODO triggers an alert: "test.py is an unrecognized file and has been sandboxed as Partially Limited". If I choose "Don't isolate it again", it doesn't help. How do I resolve this problem? The second question is: how do I set up the entire directory with all its content (executables, perl and python scripts, etc.) as trusted?